# Inserting char into active form element where cursor is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few form fields and want to insert clicked character into it (exact position of cursor) but the cursor can be focused on any form field. So if I click **a** and the cursor is between **1** and **2** of **text** element then the result should be **1a23**

So far (with my very limited jQuery knowledge) I did easy bit which correctly gets what char was clicked but getting ID of active element returns `undefined` so I cannot go any further.

This one http://jsfiddle.net/NaHTw/4/ specifies the field ID so I couldn't really work out how to inspire from it.

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hynj1sa/2/) which is half done.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chars">
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
<input type='text' name='title' value="123" id="titleField" />
<br />
<textarea name='message'id="messageField">456</textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chars ul li').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // this is fine
        var char = $(this).text();
        console.log(char);

        // these returns undefined
        console.log($(':focus').attr('id'));
        console.log($(document.activeElement).attr('id'));
        console.log($(this).parents('.item').attr('id'));

        // update 'element' content here by inserting 'char'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the last position in javascript then insert to that selection:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // bind click on textarea and input text then save positions
    var caretpos, lastitem;
    $('input[type=text], textarea').on('click keyup', function(){
        lastitem = $(this).attr('id');
        caretpos = $('#'+lastitem)[0].selectionStart;
    });

    $('#chars ul li').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // this is fine
        var char = $(this).text();
        console.log(char);
        
        // update 'element' content here by inserting 'char'
        textval = $('#'+lastitem).val();
        $('#'+lastitem).val(textval.substring(0, caretpos) + char + textval.substring(caretpos) );

        caretpos = $('#'+lastitem)[0].selectionStart;
    });
});
```

```css
#chars ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#chars li { display: inline; background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<div id="chars">
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
<input type='text' name='title' value="123" id="titleField" />
<br />
<textarea name='message' id="messageField">456</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hynj1sa/3/)

Edit 2: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hynj1sa/6/)

Comment: Nice one, nearly there so there is something missing. For example: write "Mihai" after `123` and hit **a**. The `a` char should be inserted right after your name however it gets inserted before your name instead. Expected result is `123Mihaia` not `123aMihai`.

Comment: it's nothing missing, it's inserting where the last click was ... after you write Mihai you should click again between 123 and Mihai. If you want last caret you should add and `$().on('keyup', function(){});` to add another event to change caret position.

Comment: added that function .. check now.

Comment: Excellent. Thank yo very much. +1

Comment: @MihaiIorga - Found something else. Click `a` a few times and then `b`. Unfortunately `b` will go in front of `a` instead of after.

Comment: And you can't add an caret update on insert? Check last code.

Comment: Example: Select textbox with 123 in it. Click `a` once and it becomes `123a` then click so it becomes `123ba`. That's the problem. It should read `123ab` instead.